# Variable/Command within Minipage declaration

Tags: macros, environments, minipage, variable

I have a custom `minipage` environment that may have 2 different width values with the same basic setup. I create a `\newcommand` that stores which width to use when. These `minipage`s go into a `tabular*` environment and a bunch of other stuff is done. However, I've isolate my issue in the following example.

```
\newcommand{\MinipageTableSizeLookup}[1]{
    \ifnum #1 = 3 {0.279} 
    \else {0.359}
    \fi
    }

\newenvironment{MyMiniPage}[4]{   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{ 0.279\linewidth}
        \begin{center} \textbf{#2 (#3)} \newline \textit{#4} \end{center}
    }{
    \end{minipage} 
    }
```

When calling

```
\begin{MyMiniPage}{3}{Some Header}{14}{Subheading}
    This is useful information setup in this way.
    \end{MyMiniPage}
```

succeeds only if the plain text of 0.279\linewidth is entered in the `\begin{minipage}[t]{ 0.279\linewidth}`. Swapping that out with `\MinipageTableSizeLookup{#1}` fails with error "Missing number, treated as zero." I want to be able to toggle on the fly the width of these `minitable`s when called.

I've tried including `\linewidth` in the `\MinipageTableSizeLookup` command.

Here's my preamble for reference:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{margin=0.50in} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}
```

Comment: please post examples as a single file we can run to see the issue (without all the unrelated packages) posting disconnected fragments just makes it harder to answer

Comment: but replace `{0.279} ` by `0.279 ` you can not have braces there, and put `\linewidth` after the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `0.3\linewidth` not `{0.3}\linewidth` so you need to drop the braces from your `\ifnum`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MinipageTableSizeLookup}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1 = 3
     0.279
    \else
      0.359
    \fi
    }

\newenvironment{MyMiniPage}[4]{%  
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\MinipageTableSizeLookup{#1}\linewidth}
        \begin{center} \textbf{#2 (#3)} \newline \textit{#4} \end{center}%
    }{%
    \end{minipage}%
    }

\begin{MyMiniPage}{3}{Some Header}{14}{Subheading}
    This is useful information setup in this way.
    \end{MyMiniPage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for that.